# Getting screen from a laptop motherboard

Tags: boot, motherboard, external-display

So here is my situation:

I have 3 laptop motherboards from laptops in which the screen died. These are motherboards from different era's and different manufacturers. At least one of them is a 32 BIT Toshiba Sattelite version (Nokotion pt10an) and the other is from an ASUS laptop (Asus X550CL). The third one is the unkown.

So far these board all seem to boot up to a certain degree. I connected an external screen using HDMI but no HDD or any other disk drive. I did plug in a USB keyboard.

I plug these in my external screen, which is a default 1080p screen with HDMI and VGA input. Even thought the boards seem to be booting, there is no signal going to the external screen. The "No signal" popup appears with all 3 boards on both VGA as well as HDMI. I tested to be sure the external screen with my PC using HDMI and that seems to working perfectly. Even a different older laptop and VGA connection to the external screen works like a charm.

I know that at least 1 board reacts to the USB keyboard, because CTRL-ALT-DELETE makes an LED blink on pressing the button, which also lights up on boot.

For all I at least cleared the CMOS battery.

What can I do to at the very least get an image on a screen? Any tips appreciated.

P.S.: I have none of the original screens for the laptop board so I can't test that. The RAM I have on the boards also work fine on other systems.

[EDIT]
Ah yes, my external keyboard does not have an FN key, but I tried all combinations of ctrl/alt/win/dd keys with the F1-12, to no avail :(

Comment: Sometimes you have to manually activate the external video port.  Laptops usually have a Fn key.  Sometimes you have to press than key and another F key like F4 to activate it.  Of course, different manufacturers used different keys.

Comment: Ah yes, my external keyboard does not have an FN key, but I tried all combinations of ctrl/alt/win/dd keys with the F1-12, to no avail :(

Comment: The hp keyborard part # kbar211 does in case your looking for a USB keyboard with the Fn key.  Amazon has them for $17

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Meanwhile, is there no alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I need to post a picture so it can't be in the comments so I am do it here

For the Asus X550CL

https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X550CL/E_eManual_X550CL_VL_VER7926.pdf?model=X550CL

Refer to page 39

[image]